# Nodejs project not starting/hangs

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs project running on centos 7.
I'm trying to run my nodejs project with the command `node start.js` aswell tried `sudo node start.js` but tends to be hanging up, i included a screenshot too, which you can find there: http://prntscr.com/g4ogcf
Can anybody help me with this? I'm quite clueless about that because it doesn't return any errors aswell.

My start.js application code:

```
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');
const server = require('http').Server(app);

const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./Database.js');
const db = new Database();

const cfg = require('./config/config.json');
const io = require('socket.io')(cfg.client.socket_port);
const Router = require('./Router')(db, io);
app.listen(cfg.client.server_port);
app.use(cors());
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/../public/client/app/index.html`, (err, data) => {
        if (err)
            throw err;
        res.send(data.toString())
    });
});
app.get('/media', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.cfg) {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/javascript');
        fs.readFile(`${__dirname}/config/config.json`, (err, data) => {
            if (err)
                throw err;
            res.send(`export default ${JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(data).client)}`);
        });
    }
    res.set('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
    if (req.query.avatar) {
        db.getAvatarImg(req.query.avatar).then(x => {
            var img = x[0] ? x[0].img : '';

            const data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            const buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            res.send(buf);
        });

    }
    if (req.query.background) {
        db.getBackgroundImg(req.query.background).then(x => {
            var img = x[0] ? x[0].img : '';
            const data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            const buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            res.send(buf);
        });

    }
    if (req.query.post) {
        db.getPostImg(req.query.post).then(x => {
            var img = x[0] ? x[0].img : '';
            const data = img.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
            const buf = new Buffer(data, 'base64');
            res.send(buf);
        });

    }

});
app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/../public/`));
```

Comment: Hangs? This seems like normal behavior. Can you access localhost with the port specified in `./config/config.json` ?

Comment: Add a log next to each `require` and you should be able to figure out which line it reaches. I'm not entirely convinced that it is actually hanging, as I don't see any logs and you are `listen`ing, which keeps the process alive

Comment: Can you please pass a callback to the app.listen function  as a second param ,console log something just to debug

Comment: From the screenshot you shared, I think everything looks good. Trying moving this part of your code `app.listen(cfg.client.server_port);` to the bottom of the file and give it another try.

Comment: I thought it hanged because the webpage is not available when i visit it, but thanks guys.

Comment: Look at this basic express example: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html - maybe you need to test the order of your express calls

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
console.time('app started');
```

before all of the require statements and

```
console.timeEnd('app started');
```

at the end of the start.js code. With the help of this, you can check whether your application hanged or initialized successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the program.

Just update `app.listen(cfg.client.server_port);` to

```
app.listen(cfg.client.server_port, ()=>{
   console.log("server started at port "+cfg.client.server_port);
});
```

This will log on the console a text telling you that the server has started.